# ActiveAdmin Batch Action Dynamic Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using rails 4 with ActiveAdmin. I created a batch action using a custom form to create a Task with a Build number for every selected Device. Here's what my code looks like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Device do

  def get_builds
    builds = []
    Build.all.each do |build|
      builds << [
        "[#{build.resource} - #{build.version}] #{build.file_name}",
        build.id
      ]
    end

    return builds
  end

  batch_action :create_task, form: {
    build: get_builds()
  } do |ids, inputs|

    build = Build.find(inputs[:build])

    Device.where(id: ids).each do |device|
      Task.create({
        device: device,
        build: build
      })
    end

    redirect_to admin_tasks_path
  end

end
```

**My problem is that the list of build in the batch action's form is not refreshing.** When I start my app it does have a list of all the available builds but if I add or remove a build, the build list won't be refreshed.

It is of course because the form parameter evaluate my function only once but I  can't find any documentation about having a "dynamic" form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ActiveAdmin is caching the class in memory on load, so the builds only get calculated once. To re-calculate on each load, pass a `lambda` as the value of `form`, e.g:

```
form_lambda = lambda do
  builds = Build.all.map do |build|
    ["#{ build.resource } - #{ build.version } #{ build.file_name }", build.id]
  end

  { build: builds }
end

batch_action :create_task, form: form_lambda do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Works great. I tried it with a Lambda too and it also work. Any reason you choose a Proc over a Lambda?

Comment: Force of habit. Lambda is actually a safer choice, since it handles `return` statements sanely.

Comment: Change your answer to use a Lambda and ill accept it. I too think that Lambda is a safer choice and it's what I used in my app.

Answer (score 0):

@ahmacleod's approach of recalculation on each load, by passing a lambda as the value for the form worked for me.

But I had to contend with this error

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Worked around with this change:

```
form_lambda = lambda do |id = nil|
  # ...
end
```